# jsonp, just not working.. always error

Tags: javascript, json, jquery, jsonp

I have read and read and read.. I am trying to pull a feed I have followed ever last answer i can google. I don't get what the issues are here cause firebug is fine with finding and parsing the darn json.

so try one

```
var url='http://images.wsu.edu/javascripts/tracking/configs/pick.asp';
$.getJSON(url+'?callback=?', function(data){
    alert('true');
    $.jtrack({
        load_analytics:{account:GAcode},
        trackevents:data // this can be hard codded here or set do be feed in like so
        });
});
```

FAIL yet i see it in [image: WTF?]

so

```
var url='http://images.wsu.edu/javascripts/tracking/configs/pick.asp';
$.ajax({ 
  url: url, 
  cache: false,  
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  jsonp : "callback",
  success: function(data){ 
    alert('data');
    //data=jQuery.parseJSON(data);
    $.jtrack({
        load_analytics:{account:GAcode},
        trackevents:data // this can be hard codded here or set do be feed in like so
    });
  }, 
  error: function(e, xhr){ 
    alert('error');
    alert(e);
  } 
});
```

And again FAIL .. so.. um think error would tell me yet.. nothing.. so.. lets be real and test the output it's self cause sure as hell it finds the url and I'm invoking jsop and and and.. well lets validate the output cause surely that is the issue.

[image]

So.. well I don't know.. I have hit every darn thread here from bangkok.  One one know what the deal is?

Comment: Well you are treating it was JSONP, but the screenshots and url show it as JSON, there is no callback being set.

Comment: Your link is just json, do you have API documentation? you're gonna have to set a callback ie: http://web.onassar.com/blog/2009/07/25/jsonp-vs-json-amazing-for-apis/

Comment: so I wrapped the output of the url in callback( ) and no change on the $.getJSON(url+'?callback=?', function(data){});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout this link:
[JSON Example using Callback](http://danfolkes.com/2012/02/03/web-service-using-jsonp-from-external-domain-php-jquery/)

I think the JSON returned needs to put the callback in the returned JSON.  In the example above, it's placed at the front like:

```
CALLBACKVALUE([{"id":"4","name":"FICTION","parentid":"3","getfullname":"BOOKS > FICTION"},{"id":"5","name":"NON-FICTION","parentid":"3","getfullname":"BOOKS > NON-FICTION"})
```

Comment: Ok.. did this.. and seems to pull it back but $.getJSON(url+'?callback=?', function(data){alert('true');}); still is not alerting?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are not returning JSONP content - just JSON.  You need to prepend the `callback` parameter to the start of the JSON you are currently serving and also wrap it in parenthesis.  e.g. you are currently returning:

```
[{
    "element":"#null",
    "options":{}
 }, 
   ...
]
```

and you need to be returning:

```
value_of_callback_param([{
    "element":"#null",
    "options":{}
  }, 
  ...
]);
```

The trailing `;` is optional.  See [this link](http://bob.pythonmac.org/archives/2005/12/05/remote-json-jsonp/_) which describes how it's supposed to work.

In addition I think `application/javascript` should be used for the content type instead of `application/json`, since you will be returning valid JavaScript instead of just a JSON object/array.  Also, the [jQuery docs for the `$.ajax` function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) states that the `error` callback should not called for JSONP requests.

Comment: yes danfolkes pointed out i was missing the callback value as a wrapper.. thank you for getting back.. cheers -

Answer (score 0):

Just make `pick.asp` get the value of the `callback` url parameter (called `<some string>` from now on), which gets generated by jquery and sent like this `pick.asp?callback=<some string>` to the server. Then use that value to build your response like this:

```
<some string>(<your json>);
```

Answer (score 0):

this alerts "#null"

```
var url = 'http://images.wsu.edu/javascripts/tracking/configs/pick.asp';
$.getJSON(url + '?callback=?', function(data) {
  alert(data[0].element);
});
```

here is what comes back:

```
callback([
    {
        "element":"#null",
        "options":{}
    },{
        "element":"a#hover",
        "options":{
            "category":"hover",
            "label":"function(ele){ return ( ($(ele).attr('title')!='' && typeof($(ele).attr('title')) !=='undefined' ) ? $(ele).attr('title') : $(ele).attr('href') ) }"
        }
    },{
        "element":"a[href$='.jpg'],a[href$='.gif'],a[href$='.png'],a[href$='.ppt'],a[href$='.pdf'],a[href$='.doc'],a[href$='.docx']",
        "options":{
            "category":"download",
            "label":"function(ele){ return ( ($(ele).attr('title')!='' && typeof($(ele).attr('title')) !=='undefined' ) ? $(ele).attr('title') : $(ele).attr('href') ) }"
            }
    },{
        "element":"a:not([href*='mailto('])",
        "options":{
            "category":"email"
            }
    },{
        "element":"a:not([href*='wsu.edu'])",
        "options":{
            "category":"outbound"
            }
    },{
        "element":"a[href*='wsu.edu']",
        "options":{
                "category":"internal",
                "noninteraction":"true"
            }
    }
])
```

Comment: yes danfolkes pointed out i was missing the callback value as a wrapper.. you had just missed it .. thank you for getting back.. cheers -